# Comment traduire « [X is] soft-balling what [Y] is now shooting at us with a cannon » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques, formulation-idiomatique

> [...] public health restrictions are "[soft-balling](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/softball) what COVID is now
> shooting at us with a cannon." ([cbc.ca](https://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/manitoba/manitoba-doctors-react-updated-pubic-health-restrctions-1.6299055))

On parle des règles de santé publique. On part de l'analogie avec la mollesse dans un [sport](https://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26505437) et on reste dans le paradigme du lancer en employant une forme de comparaison avec le coup de canon pour signifier l'inadéquation, le manque de sérieux.

---

Comment va-t-on traduire et peut-on reproduire l'analogie sportive du lancer et la comparaison imagée et pourquoi est-ce souhaitable ou non ici ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132752/discussion-on-question-by-noello-miqueron-comment-traduire--x-is-soft-balling).

Answer (score 2):

- Avec leurs mesurettes, les autorités jouent à la baballe alors qu'en face, le covid a sorti l'artillerie lourde.
- Les autorités jouent petit bras face au covid qui lui, tire à balles réelles.
- Ces restrictions sanitaires, ce sont des fusils à bouchon contre la mitraille du covid.

Comment: +1 pour les mesurettes et l'artillerie lourde.

Comment: "Tire à balles réelles" Tout à fait pertinent!

Answer (score 2):

Je dirais quelque chose comme ça (conservant la métaphore, mais en oubliant le softball qui n'est pas connu en France) :

> Les restrictions sanitaires actuelles en réponse à l'épidémie de COVID équivalent à s'armer d'une raquette de tennis pour riposter à la grosse Bertha.

Comment: Donc j'ai [vérifié](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grosse_Bertha), je ne connaissais pas cette référence à des éléments d'artillerie de la Première. C'est courant ?

Comment: @NoëlloMiqueron Oui c'est une référence assez courante. Un terme presque générique pour parler de (très) gros canons.

Answer (score 1):

Dans le doute, je colle à la métaphore d'origine autant que la grammaire me le permet.

"Les règles sanitaires sont une batte de soft-ball qui prétend dévier les boulets dont le COVID nous canonne. "

"Les règles sanitaires sont la batte de soft-ball que nous opposons aux boulets dont le COVID nous canonne. "

"Les règles sanitaires contre le COVID, c'est nous abriter d'une canonnade derrière une batte de soft-ball. "